# Not able to update form data in React

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am using react to accept input from the user. And when the user submits I want to get rid of the form and display the user input data.

I am not able to see the user input data on my result page. I have uploaded the screenshots and the code below.

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {isFormOn: true, isResult: false , firstname: "", lastname: ""};
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(){
        this.setState(state => ({
            isFormOn: !state.isFormOn,
            isResult: !state.isResult
        }));
    }

    handleChange({ event }) {
        this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
     }


    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                { this.state.isFormOn && (
                   <div>
                     First name :
                     <input type="text" name="firstname" onChange={this.handleChange}  /><br />
                     Last name :
                     <input type="text" name="lastname" onChange={this.handleChange}  /><br />
                     <br />
                     <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        {this.state.isFormOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
                     </button>
                   </div>
                )}
                { this.state.isResult && (
                   <div>
                       <h4>The name entered is : {this.state.firstname} {this.state.lastname} </h4>
                       <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                           {this.state.isFormOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
                       </button>
                   </div>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[Render form to accept user input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woe0d.png)

[Result of the user entered information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS0Lh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler (`handleChange`) is [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the event object, and trying to extract a property called `event` from it, which doesn't exist.

You need to use the event object directly instead:

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  });
}
```